# Importing files from Panoramio to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, openlayers-2

I need to visualize in QGIS the density of photographs taken in seven municipalities of the central Italy: Perugia, Magione, Passignano, Umbertide, Deruta, Corciano, Torgiano.

I'm wondering if there is a method to export the Panoramio georeferenced features (e.g. the places where photos were taken) in a format that can be opened in QGIS (csv, shp or others), or if there is a method to import the Panoramio georeferenced features as OpenLayers in QGIS.

Can anybody help me?